# Can you generate a drilldown subreport to a tooltip in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I was poking around the internet and was curious if anyone on StackOverflow has ever managed to successfully bind a SubReport to a tooltip.  I kind of was hearing multiple answers online.  The most common assertion is that you cannot because tooltips only take expressions and cannot relate.  Another assertion is that you can add custom code, which I have only done in labs, to get it to an expression that can then be used.

One of the things I wish SSRS would do out of the box would be to 'pop-out' drill down reports.  Due to intense operations I understand you can't relate a lot of data but for just simple grids of details this would be fine.

So far I have been able to either set up subreports to drill to other pages or I found a blog where someone managed to use JavaScript to present the subreport in a set window size.  I have used that as well: http://tavislovell.com/wordpress/how-to-make-ssrs-reports-in-a-performancepoint-dashboard-pop-out-or-open-in-a-new-window-2/

The issue is that I want 'hover over' feature that is found in some other tools.  Has anyone successfully done a subreport or 2nd dataset in a tooltip that can be dynamic rows?  I essentially want to hover over a cell and get a report to popout at a user for certain cells.  Again I understand this could potentially be intense but I would scope it so it would be minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, doing this with just SSRS is an uphill battle. There are a few reasons for this: very few report renderers could support this functionality, SSRS doesn't nicely support inserting custom javascript, potential performance issues. &c, &c. I don't think you'll get far there.

**But**

If this functionality were absolutely required, my recommendation is to use a custom wrapper website: users would go to the custom website to load a report. The website would make calls to SSRS to retrieve reports. It would scan the resulting HTML for some predetermined special string: `INSERTREPORTTOOLTIP(CLIENTID=45)` to determine where and what "tooltip charts" need to be generated and inserted.

Not for the faint of heart, I would think this would be at least a 20 hour undertaking if all went really smoothly.

(Also, true "tooltips" implementation is browser dependent, so you really need a div with visibility and perhaps position dynamically controlled.)

Whether you should use SSRS or build your own "report" web page depends on how much other SSRS functionality you are leveraging.

Comment: Those are great points you made.  At this point I am trying to leverage all potential 'abilities' possible out of SSRS and then I may decide to use it or not for a Content Management Site Dashboard.  I have looked into other technologies of Crystal Reports and High Reports but I know SSRS very well all ready so my time would be spent learning a new language as well as implementing it if I changed.  If you also have any reporting framework suggestions, please let me know.  My only requirements are flexibility with generated objects and that the framework can be built overtop of .NET 4.5 or 4.0.